# Using RunningValue in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Trying to use the following expression in a matrix in my report:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!orderCount.Value,SUM,"RedemptionData")
```

But it gives the error:

```
The Value expression for the text box '' has a scope parameter that is not valid for RunningValue, RowNumber or Previous. The scoke parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to the name of a containing group within the Tablix''.
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Im such an idiot. Just realised there is no scope on this. Used the following code which works perfectly fine:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!orderCount.Value,SUM,Nothing)
```